# Strange Pixel Stretching

Tags: rendering

I am trying to figure out why the render view is showing the image with stretched pixels. Saving the image and viewing it the pixels are normal, it's just a problem in Blender render view. In render view setting fractional zoom to 1:1 or numpad 1  does not fix it. I am on blender 2.93 alpha. Bug?[image]